# SFTP File transfer from local to Server machine on Windows OS using JMeter

Tags: ssh, cmd, jmeter, sftp, invoke

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uZPae6YBPE6Ufc23IszKE5mP0NQjOG5V/view?usp=sharing)[enter image description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uZPae6YBPE6Ufc23IszKE5mP0NQjOG5V/view?usp=sharing)I am new to JMeter and need to perform load tests for SFTP Server.

Scenario:

Need to copy a file(s) from local machine (Windows 10 OS) to Server (Windows 10 OS). After that a schedule job gets executed and the same file is consumed by Biztalk process and the XML file name reflects in Database with Success/Failure/Duplicate status.

When I am executing my command in cmd directly then the process is working fine. But unable to do the same with JMeter. I have tried all the listed ways available on the Internet using OS Process Sampler, SSH Command and SSH SFTP Sampler available in JMeter but couldn't succeed so far.

Note: Unable to invoke cmd via OS Process Sampler in JMeter (Please provide steps if you have done it earlier).

Comment: I have gone through the mentioned link but unable to perform the same in my case. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter

Comment: Could you help with errors you are getting in jmeter and what command you are trying from windows command line

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I have uploaded a video for better understanding and also attached screenshots for cmd and database screen for your reference.

Comment: Possible to make the video public? It is asking for access

Comment: I have updated the link. Please check now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing:

1. your command which "works"
2. your JMeter configuration
3. output of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener (all tabs)
4. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) contents

Here is the evidence that it works using the OS Process Sampler:

[image]

And here is the same using SSH SFTP Sampler:

[image]

More information: [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter)

Comment: I have uploaded a video for better understanding and also attached screenshots for cmd and database screen for your reference.

Comment: I have tried both the ways as per your suggestion but unable to perform the load test successfully. The same command which is mentioned in OS Process Sampler is working fine in cmd and data gets reflected in Database as well.